# If and $null statements not working

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I wrote this script to copy security groups.  If the group does not exist the script should create the group in the same location of the source group.  The problem I'm having is my script is not getting to the `if` statement. Anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
[string]$SourceGroup,

[Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
[string]$DestinationGroup
)

$SourceGroupCheck = Get-ADGroup -Identity $SourceGroup 
$DestinationGroupCheck = Get-ADGroup -Identity $DestinationGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


 Function copy-to-Group{
 $Group = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $SourceGroupCheck.SamAccountName

 if($DestinationGroupCheck -ne $null){
   foreach ($Person in $Group) { 
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $DestinationGroupCheck.SamAccountName -Members $Person.distinguishedname 

                                 }
                            }

 else {
 New-ADGroup -Name $DestinationGroup -Path ($SourceGroupCheck.DistinguishedName -replace '^[^,]*,','') -GroupScope Global
    foreach ($Person in $Group) { 
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $DestinationGroup.SamAccountName -Members $Person.distinguishedname 

                                 }
 }
                         }

copy-to-Group
```

Comment: Why did you make it a function? I would get rid of the `Function copy-to-group{` line, and the last `}` in the script, as well as the last line.

Answer (score 0):

works for me with an existing destination group but Im guessing you are getting the issue when the destination group does NOT exist. I assume you are getting an error similar to: "Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=,DC=com" And when you get the error your if else statement fails...

you can bypass that by doing:

```
$DestinationGroupCheck = Get-ADGroup -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $DestinationGroup}
```

This will prevent any error when a group isnt found and will get the if else check to fire off correctly.  As the Mad Technician said not sure why you are using a function you can do with out it if you want to.